# TypeError: Failed to fetch when fetching in javascript but works when fetch url is put in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, fetch-api

I'm just trying to make a fetch to grab the reviews for a restaurant using their placeID. When I use this URL in the browser, I get the results but when using it in a simple html/JavaScript app I get TypeError: Failed to fetch.
Here is the URL I use that works in the browser (note you need your own google API key)
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=API_KEY_HERE&placeid=ChIJZ92Qj31CXIYR1i6OU-1uHp0&fields=reviews
Also I think it's strange in the network I get a status code of 200 and the response is red but when I click on it I can see all the data.
And below is my simple HTML/Javascript code for trying to get the fetch to work

Heres the HTML

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=ENTER_KEY_HERE&libraries=places"></script>
  <script src="./practice.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the javascript

```
async function getdata (){
    try{
const response = await fetch("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=AIzaSyA-_w_z6Isz9dMp6jRSF43Kpefslg9_wHg&placeid=ChIJZ92Qj31CXIYR1i6OU-1uHp0&fields=reviews")
if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('something went wrong!');
  }
console.log(response)
const items = await response.json();
console.log(items)
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
}
getdata()
```

Ugh Maybe I'm just dumb but I've been reading through google documentation and debugging / researching for the past three hours. I was originally trying to get google reviews for a restaurant to show up on a react app (MERN STACK) but have had no luck and made a simple html and JavaScript version to try and debug it. Would appreciate any tips or help as I had no luck in documentation, google or ChatGPT.

- I've tried running the app in a private browser to see if adblockers or something was blocking it with no luck. and also, I can make other fetch request with different URLs so I assume its not that.
- I've tried using Axios instead of fetch with no luck
- Tried making the API call using .then and await methods.
- Googled but found no similar issues
- ChatGPT sending me in circles
- I know its not my network or api key because the URL works in browser
- I don't believe its cors because the request works in browser

Comment: Running the code in my browser gave a CORS error: `Access to fetch at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=AIzaSyA-_w_z6Isz9dMp6jRSF43Kpefslg9_wHg&placeid=ChIJZ92Qj31CXIYR1i6OU-1uHp0&fields=reviews' from origin 'https://stackoverflow.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`. The URL works when typed directly into the address bar, but does not work when `fetch`ing from this site.

Comment: I see `GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=AIzaSyA-_w_z6Isz9dMp6jRSF43Kpefslg9_wHg&placeid=ChIJZ92Qj31CXIYR1i6OU-1uHp0&fields=reviews net::ERR_FAILED 200` (colored red in the browser console, indicating that something does not load properly). That link can be clicked and does give some text in return (json format), but then the browser just won't let you use the results in a script.

Comment: I assumed it couldn't be a cors issue since its just a simple html/js app

Comment: Well you assumed wrong. CORS does not care. Of course the request works in the browser because loading it in the browser directly is okay. Use their api

Comment: sorry their documentation is confusing to me because I copied the url from their website

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

Comment: guess I am dumb I was using
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details
ill try that doc

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some people pointing out the correct documentation I solved it and found a way to get reviews wish it was as simple as a fetch but you need to load a map like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Place Details Example</title>
  <script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY_HERE&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="place-details"></div>

  <script>
    function initMap() {
      const apiKey = ''; // Replace with your API key
      const placeId = 'ChIJZ92Qj31CXIYR1i6OU-1uHp0'; // Replace with the desired place ID

      const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'));

      const request = {
        placeId: placeId,
        fields: [ 'geometry', 'reviews']
      };

      service.getDetails(request, (place, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          displayPlaceDetails(place);
        } else {
          console.error('Error fetching place details:', status);
        }
      });
    }

    function displayPlaceDetails(place) {
      const detailsContainer = document.getElementById('place-details');
      detailsContainer.innerHTML = `
        <h3>Reviews:</h3>
        <ul>
          ${place.reviews.map(review => `<li>${review.text} (Rating: ${review.rating})</li>`).join('')}
        </ul>
      `;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```